# Why did I have problems with alembic migrations

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, alembic

Project structue(only directory with DB migrations):

```
--db_manage:
  alembic.ini
  --alembic:
    env.py
    script.py.mako
    README
    --versions:
      #migration files
```

When I try to run command: `python db_manage/alembic/env.py`, I have response like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_manage/alembic/env.py", line 8, in <module>
    config = context.config
AttributeError: module 'alembic.context' has no attribute 'config'
```

In which case I have that problem?
**P.S.** 
File `alembic.ini`:

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic

# template used to generate migration files
# file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
#truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; this defaults
# to numus/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar %(here)s/bat numus/versions

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://test:oe50yxXOspYDsaXSO7Gf@localhost/test


# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

File `env.py`:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from alembic import context
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config, pool
from logging.config import fileConfig

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = None

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url, target_metadata=target_metadata, literal_binds=True)

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix='sqlalchemy.',
        poolclass=pool.NullPool)

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()

if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

Comment: Try `python db_manage/alembic/env.py --autogenerate`

Comment: @Mekicha Nothing changed, same output

Comment: It'd seem you're running the command from a different directory than where your `alembic.ini` resides. Try passing it explicitly using `-c` or `--config`, as in `alembic --config db_manage/alembic.ini ...`. Not sure if this is the root cause, but worth a try.

Comment: @IljaEverilä As I understand, I should to run that command in `db_manage/` directory?

Comment: That'd help as well, if I've understood the situation correctly. Not to mention that to my knowledge you're not supposed to run the `env.py` directly yourself, but use the `alembic` migration tool, which then runs your `env.py`.

Comment: Btw I hope your database isn't bound so that it is open to the internet / those credentials aren't real.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong in the way you try to invoke the migration tool. Firstly, you should use the `alembic` script instead of trying to run the `env.py` directly. From the [tutorial](http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/tutorial.html):

> `env.py` - This is a Python script that is run **whenever the alembic migration tool is invoked**. At the very least, it contains instructions to configure and generate a SQLAlchemy engine, procure a connection from that engine along with a transaction, and then invoke the migration engine, using the connection as a source of database connectivity.

Secondly, though you can keep your `alembic.ini` wherever, the default behaviour is to look in the current directory:

> Alembic placed a file `alembic.ini` into the current directory. This is a file that the `alembic` script looks for when invoked. This file can be anywhere, either in the same directory from which the `alembic` script will normally be invoked, or if in a different directory, can be specified by using the `--config` option to the `alembic` runner.

So if it is held somewhere else, you must instruct alembic about the location using the `-c`, or `--config`, switch. For example:

```
alembic --config db_manage/alembic.ini
```

Comment: It help me a lot, but now I have new problem: my credentials are wrong, when I try to run `alembic upgrade head` it tell me that my DB password is wrong. In which place I can change it? P.S. Sorry for stupid question, I`m new at python, and try to set up existing project.

Comment: The `sqlalchemy.url` in the `alembic.ini` is the place to handle that. Also check that your Postgresql configuration allows the needed authentication methods in the [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), if need be.

Comment: @CharlieOConor Because you **did not ask**. Instead you write a long rant that is entirely besides the point of this particular Q/A, and I assume that the other negative feedback goes with the rant.

Comment: @CharlieOConor Now were you to ask a proper question detailing your actual problem instead of just venting, then maybe someone familiar with the [alembic API](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/index.html) could come up with a solution.

Comment: Very true. I was very frustrated last night, but have gotten a better handle on things now. Sorry for my lack of control.

Comment: @CharlieOConor These are trying times. Glad to hear things are for the better.

Comment: For what it's worth, you did have a point. I think that the "best of both worlds" solution are tools that have the command line and configuration for the usual cases, backed up by a library that implements the logic.