# AttributeError: module 'alembic.context' has no attribute 'config'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, alembic

I have imported context from alembic. But the variables like config and configure are unavailable in the package. What could be the reason ?

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`alembic.context` is only available for the `env.py` script when it is executed through the `alembic` command, and provided that the `alembic` command is executed from a folder containing an `alembic.ini` file specifying the Alembic configuration to use.

Otherwise, the `alembic` module does not have a `context` property.

For more information, see [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46050669/939364).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had multiple bases and had specified an incorrect directory in the `version_locations` setting, so I suspect alembic was trying to look at those files or something.

Answer (score -5):

You may try:

```
from alembic import *
```

Then, you can explore what functions, classes, and attributes available by:

```
dir(alembic)
```

I hope this helps.